# how to fix overlap in xlabels using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hello all i'm currently trying to plot some data using matplotlib. Unfortunately every time I plot the xlabels overlap each other. How can I go about getting this to space out the labels?Code snippet below. my dict has keys of 'neighborhood' and values of int

```
#do data visualization here
myList = dict.items()
#myList = sorted(myList) 
x, y = zip(*myList) 
plt.xlabel("Neighborhoods")
plt.ylabel("# of Public Art")
plt.title("Public Art Distribution in Pittsburgh")
plt.xscale('log', base=3)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[I'm trying to get the labels to not overlap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep8qH.png)

*EDIT: thank you to the two suggestions of rotation and to increase figure size. By using these two I was able to get it displaying correctly*

Comment: Try `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`

Comment: Thank you that did help a lot. the only other issue right now is that they're spaced to close together. Is there a way to increase the spacing between the xticks themselves?

Comment: Side note, but somehow a line graph doesn't seem appropriate for your data.

Comment: You could add this at the start of your code to increase the figure size? `plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))`

Comment: Amazing using the rotation and increasing the figure size fixed my issues! Thank you to everyone who helped me.

Comment: @BigBen I switched to a bar graph and it looks way better. Thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
```

You can try to set the frequency to five or more.